# changing one list to another in .net

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have list e.g:

```
list1=
{{id=1,address=a},
{id=1,address=b},
{id=2,address=c},
{id=2,address=d}}
```

how can i change this list into something like

```
list2=
{{id=1,address={a,b}},
{id=2,address={c,d}}}
```

that is putting same id's list into one with inner list containing other elements

Comment: Well you need to change `address` to also be a list

Comment: Please show some effort in solving it yourself. There are many questions and examples for group by

Answer (score 2):

`group` is your friend here. Assuming the output type's `address` property is a `List<T>` something like:

```
var res = (from x in input
           group x by x.id into grouped
           select new Output {
             id = grouped.Key,
             address = grouped.ToList()
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: input and Output=??

Comment: @ConfuseD your `list1` and the type of your `list2`.